# convert all json decoded objects to array in php

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON decoded object(see the picture):

[image: print screen from browser]

I want to convert whole object to array(also children object). When I do something like this

```
$parent_object = (array)$parent_object;
```

It converts only parent object, children objects are still objects. Is there way to convert all objects to array at once, instead of using (array) every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better set the 2nd argument `TRUE` for [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function (*When `TRUE`, returned `objects` will be converted into associative `arrays`.*) Like this -

```
json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the solution from [here](http://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/567/php-recursively-convert-an-object-to-an-array) help?

```
function object_to_array($obj) {
    if(is_object($obj)) $obj = (array) $obj;
    if(is_array($obj)) {
        $new = array();
        foreach($obj as $key => $val) {
            $new[$key] = object_to_array($val);
        }
    }
    else $new = $obj;
    return $new;       
}
```

This function recursively creates a new array which contains anything except objects

Comment: thanks for replying. it works! but there's easier way - json_decode($json, TRUE);